# GridView in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am bit new to Asp.net GridView, and I am facing the following problem.
I have a gridview placed in an ascx. This ascx is loaded dynamically within an aspx, in its Page_Init method
Control control = LoadControl("~/grid.ascx");
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(control);

The grid is bound to a IList (which is populated from the data access layer). I have a button field in the grid, which is used to call the delete function in DA layer for the row (performs this call in GridView1_RowCommand()).

My question is, I dont see the grid view getting refreshed after I perform the delete. I placed the code to re-read and bind data to gridview in many places, but none seems to work.

Notes:
1. The loading of ascx is done in an ajax call for the aspx
2. Delete function actually modifies the 'Status' column of 'User' to 'Deleted' which I need to see in the gridview after I do so

Can you please help me?

Edit:
It seems that RowDataBound event is fired (for each row of course) after page load, and then only the button command event fire. Though I set the modified DS and DataBind on the gridview, it never fires the RowDataBound afterwards. Any idea why?
Thanks in advance.

Anuruddha

Answer (score 0):

you need to rebind the grid in GridView1_RowCommand() with the new datasource once again

Comment: Thanks Ali for the reply. This works in a sample test I've done, but not on the application I am working on. I wonder what the difference is. It seems that no matter what I change in the datasource, the gridview displays the same. Seems it takes the values from viewstate. Wonder what the error is :(